# Can't fix migration conflict in Django

Tags: python, django, database, migration

I am having an issue resolving a migration conflict. Normally when these things happen we've been able to merge the files together using "`python manage.py makemigrations --merge`".

However, this time we're getting a  `Could not find common ancestor of {'0001_initial', '0005_removed_custom_form_model_changed_name_to_staff_reports'}` error. Several hours later and we've made no progress in repairing this.

The issue arose after we deleted an app and created a new one to replace it.

Here are the things I've tried already:

- Returning to a previous migration using "python manage.py <app_name> <older_migration>". (Doing this displays the same merge conflict I'm trying to avoid)
- Restoring the apps.py file for the deleted app and  adding the app back into installed_apps, and then to backtrack using "python manage.py <app_name> <older_migration>" again. (Doing this causes the same merge conflict error)

I'm not too familiar with migrations myself, so I'm quickly running out of ideas, and unfortunately dropping the database is not an option in this scenario.

Here are the migration files in question:

**0001_intial.py:**

```
import django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb
import django.core.serializers.json
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('properties', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomFormDeclarations',
            fields=[
                ('deleted', models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)),
                ('date_entered', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('last_update', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('name', models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)),
                ('fields', django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(default=list, encoder=django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder)),
                ('user_type', models.CharField(choices=[['', 'Choose a User Type'], ['admin', 'Admin'], ['coorporate', 'Coorporate'], ['onsite_manager', 'Onsite Manager'], ['onsite_staff', 'Onsite Staff'], ['maintenance', 'Maintenance']], db_index=True, max_length=100)),
            ],
            options={
                'permissions': [('view_customforms', 'Can view custom forms')],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='CustomFormSubmissions',
            fields=[
                ('deleted', models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True)),
                ('id', models.AutoField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('values', django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(default=list, encoder=django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder)),
                ('last_updated', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('date_entered', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('form', models.ForeignKey(db_column='form_id', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='submissions', to='custom_forms.CustomFormDeclarations')),
                ('property', models.ForeignKey(db_column='property_id', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='properties.Property')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
                'default_permissions': ('add', 'change', 'delete', 'view', 'undelete'),
            },
        ),
    ]
```

**0005_removed_custom_form_model_changed_name_to_staff_reports**

from django.db import migrations

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('custom_forms', '0004_removed_custom_form_model_changed_name_to_staff_reports'),
        ('users', '0008_removed_custom_form_model_changed_name_to_staff_reports'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='CustomFormDeclarations',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='CustomFormSubmissions',
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Which app did you delete? Is it one of the migration `dependencies`?

Comment: We deleted custom_forms (which is one of the dependencies). I attempted to restore the app (just by creating another app.py) but the error didn't resolve.

Answer (score 0):

If you exhaust your options with django migrations then you can try to recreate the database as follows:

Dump the data from (assumming) you production environment.

```
python manage.py dumpdata > fixtures/data.json
```

Backup your migrations by copying them to a different folder. Then remove them from the project.

Create a parallel database & connect your dev/stage to the database then...

```
python manage.py createmigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata fixtures/data.json
```

Verify that the application is performing correctly and your data is correct.

Then if successful, you can either connect your production environment to the newly created database or perform the same process on the production database itself.

If the above does not work you might need to specify natural-foreign or/and natural-primary keys in your dumpdata. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata for more information